# Make textboxt visible when user checks `Other` button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a radio button that gets its values dynamically from the database.

One of the database values is called `Other'.

If a user checks this `Other` radio button, make textbox visible so user can type into it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The code below doesn't work.

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Bold="False"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
</tr>

Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        'Dim questionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim questionid As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(questionid.Value)
        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                rbl.DataBind()
            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
            Case "T"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub RadioButton1_OnCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim RadioButton1 As RadioButtonList = TryCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
    If RadioButton1 IsNot Nothing Then
        If RadioButton1.SelectedValue = "Other" Then
            Dim datalistrow As DataList = TryCast(RadioButton1.NamingContainer, DataList)
            Dim TxtOther As TextBox = TryCast(datalistrow.FindControl("TxtOther"), TextBox)
            TxtOther.Visible = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I will also like to add that the radio button value for other is 33.

In other words, `<input id="DataList1_RadioButtonList1_5_2_5" type="radio" name="DataList1$ctl06$RadioButtonList1" value="33" />`

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Tairoc ,

the values what you are binding to radio button as

```
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
```

Like say Data Base values are Val1, Val2,Val3 and Other

out of these 4 options which is the selected value of radiobuttonlist, where you are setting..

if you are setting your radiobuttonlist selected value in DataList1_ItemDataBound event..

you can write the code as follows..

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Bold="False"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Visible="false"  runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
</tr>

Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        'Dim questionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim questionid As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(questionid.Value)
        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                rbl.DataBind()

      // you juss binded the radiobuttonlist but you havent set the selected value..
     // there should be selected value "Other" so that based on the selected value we                             
     //can make the textbox1 Visible

            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
            Case "T"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

If you not setting the radiobutton selected value in RowDataBound event
Once the Radio button list is loaded with Content

like say for example

Row 1) Val1  Val2  Val3 Other

Row 2) Val1  Val2  Val3 Other

Row 3) Val1  Val2  Val3 Other

When user Select "Other" Option in radiobutton list then in the Radiobutton OnSelectedIndexChanged  event have to write like this..

```
    Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim RadioButton1 As RadioButtonList = TryCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
    If RadioButton1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim datalistrow As DataList = TryCast(RadioButton1.NamingContainer, DataList)
        Dim TxtOther As TextBox = TryCast(datalistrow.FindControl("TxtOther"), TextBox)

        If RadioButton1.SelectedValue = "Other" Then

            TxtOther.Visible = True
        Else
            TxtOther.Visible = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub TextBox1_OnTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TextBox1.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        RadioButton1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: good to hear from you again and thanks a lot for your help.

First, I am getting error that TextBox1 and RadioButton1 are not declared.

I am getting this error on TextBox1_OncTextChanged sub.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  Protected Sub TextBox1_OnTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim TextBox1 As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)
    If TextBox1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim RadioButton1 As RadioButtonList = TryCast(TextBox1.Parent.FindControl("RadioButton1"), RadioButtonList)
        If TextBox1.Text IsNot Nothing Then
            RadioButton1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```